# show php & html codes as codes in browser

Tags: php, html

I know I can use `htmlentities` to convert `html/php` codes and show them in browser.
I am also aware of `preg_match` to remove `< code> < /code>` from a string.

I would like to know how the comment systems work in most of the sites including stackoverflow

when a user enter a comment they can put any number of `< pre>< /pre>` or `< code>< /code>` blocks and when I want to show those comments in browser I want to replace only those parts inside the tags as codes. I dont want to use htmlentities to show the complete comment

```
This is a single comment entered by a user
here is a text that < br> < em>I want to show as html < /em>
< code>< ? php code goes here ?> </ code>
User write something else here 
< code>< ? php second code goes here ?> </ code>
```

how I should save and show the above in browser so that the html is shown as html and code part as normal text

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. give us an example of an input and an output?

Comment: In most of the case, a code editor plugin is used because the highlighting job is so complexe it doesn't worth the time passed on it. You will find plenty of it in the internet.

Comment: I'd use http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php with http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php. If you want to highlight multiple languages though it is going to get harder..

Comment: You need to parse the HTML, extract the HTML content of those elements, convert it to text, put it back as text, then filter out the remaining HTML to remove any unsafe elements or attributes.

Comment: May be you need: [strip_tags()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strip_tags.asp).